# 2sxc toolbar not visible after upgrade to DNN 9.6.4

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

After upgrading DNN from 9.3 to 9.6 and upgrading 2sxc to 11.10.1, the 2sxc toolbar is no longer visible.

Here are the errors returned by the console.

What may have happened?

Thanks

[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ4MT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server is not handing out JS files like it should. Basically JS files should just be simply delivered and work.

So the issue you have is not really related to 2sxc - it's an IIS or web.config issue. Best check the windows server event log to see why it doesn't want to hand out JS files.

Comment: The customer has checked the delivery of the js files on the server, everything seems ok.

The problem continues to exist. The problem now occurs randomly. Sometimes the toolbar appears and other times it doesn't appear.

This is a Load Balancing environment, could it be a problem due to this? Could it be that sometimes the settings are not loaded from the chosen machine?

DNN Version 09.06.04 2sxc Versione 11.22